# У активного пункта меню в WordPress нет дополнительного класса?

Tags: wordpress

Создал дополнительное меню ("Меню ресторана"), из ссылок на записи. В functions.php, зарегистрировал его:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'matchpoint' ),
        'Меню ресторана'    => 'Главное меню ресторана',
    ) );
```

В шаблоне вызвал:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
     'menu'=>'Меню ресторана',
     'container'       => '',
     'menu_class'      => '',
     'menu_id'         => '',
 ) );
 ?>
```

Но WordPress, почему-то не хочет к активному пункту прописывать дополнительный класс. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: (загрузку записей на нужную  страницу делал через ajax)

Comment: поищите в файлах темы (вероятнее всего в functions.php) фильтр `nav_menu_css_class`, он работает с классами отдельного пункта меню. Если он используется, то проверьте, что не отменяет вывод класса `current`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ищи класс `current_*` у `<li>`